# Referencing external library projects in Android Studio (v0.8.9)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a custom library that needs to be referenced in about 10 projects. Everything works fine in Eclipse but I want to migrate them to Android Studio in order to take advantage of the build system. I've already check

[Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle)

[How to share a single library source across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243269/android-studio-0-5-how-to-share-a-single-library-source-across-multiple-proje)

and some other links and docs in Gradleware but I don't get to make my projects compile.

My file structure is like:

+projects

|+libraryProject

|+---workspace

|+------projectSrc

|

|+project0

|+---workspace

|+------projectSrc0

|

|+project1

|+---workspace

|+------projectSrc1

.
.

|+projectN

|+---workspace

|+------projectSrcN

Each project contains docs, design files, etc... and therefore is no convenient to have the src in the same root folder.

In my "project1", **settings.gradle** file I've used:

```
include ':module-custom-lib'
project(':module-custom-lib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../../libraryProject/workspace/projectSrc')
```

In my **build.gradle** file, dependencies section I add:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':..:..:..:libraryProject:workspace:projectSrc')
    ....
}
```

But I get an error saying that the project wasn't found.

I've also used the following approach:

```
def customLib = file('../../../libraryProject/workspace/projectSrc')
settings.createProjectDescriptor(rootProjectDescriptor, 'module-custom-lib', customLib)
include ':module-custom-lib'
```

Then in the **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module-custom-lib')
    ....
}
```

Please help. Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:**  I've managed to get it working by adding the module **app** as a suffix in the project dir.:

```
include ':module-custom-lib'
project(':module-custom-lib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../../libraryProject/workspace/projectSrc/app')
```

Now the library members resolve perfectly, but the project's 'R' resource class can not be resolved. So if I do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

it fails to find that resource. Cleaning and rebuilding the project doesn't fixes the issue.

**EDIT 2:** Apparently, there was a problem with the manifest merging 'cause the problem was fixed once I adjusted the minSdk and targetSdk of both projects. The previous solution work perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first attempt has a simpler syntax, and should work. Your **settings.gradle** file looks okay:

```
include ':module-custom-lib'
project(':module-custom-lib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../../libraryProject/workspace/projectSrc')
```

though you should be cautious about including a relative path there -- Android Studio may not use the same working directory as a build you do from the command line, so referencing things relative to `rootDir` may help alleviate problems.

In the `dependencies` block of a module's build file, you need to reference a module the same way you do in **settings.gradle**, so you'd use something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':module-custom-lib')
}
```

In `dependencies` blocks, you're linking to projects using Gradle's project namespace, and since you've already explicitly set up the root directory of the library module, you don't need to try to locate it in the filesystem here. That `:..:..:..` syntax wouldn't work anyway to reference a module that's outside of your project's root directory, as this one is.

Comment: It gives me the error "Configuration with name 'default' not found."

Comment: Any hint? What does that message really means?

Comment: It means it's not finding a module at the place pointed to by the config in settings.gradle -- it's likely not finding its build.gradle at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider bundling "releases" of your library to a Maven repository (possibly your local Maven repo). This way you can reference your library from any other project that needs to use it just like you do with 3rd party libraries.

Comment: I have plenty of projects that are still gonna be referenced from Eclipse (during migration process) so I don't want to push to local maven repo nor deploy as aar.