# Android Studio: Adding a library outside of the project root

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libraries

I have two projects, A and B, and would like to share some code between them via a library project, C.  What is the proper way to do this such that:

1. A and B and C are all in separate projects. (Not in the same directory at all)
2. Changes to C are used in A or B automatically without re-importing C.

I'm fairly new to Android Studio and I've been running into all sorts of issues here.  I really just want to use source code that is located outside the project root.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like the question asked (and answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840543/referencing-external-library-projects-in-android-studio-v0-8-9).

To sum up Scott Barta's answer:

> **settings.gradle:**
>
> ```
> include ':module-custom-lib'
> project(':module-custom-lib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../../libraryProject/workspace/projectSrc')
> ```
>
> A's and B's **build.gradle:**
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile project(':module-custom-lib')
> }
> ```

So, assuming a file structure like this:

```
+-- AndroidStudioProjects
|   +-- CoreLibs
|       +-- app (empty)
|       +-- myJavaCoreLib
|       +-- anotherJavaCoreLib
|   +-- AndroidApp1
|       +-- app
|   +-- AndroidApp2
|       +-- app
|   +-- AndroidApp3
|       +-- app
```

...the code would be:

**settings.gradle:**

```
include ':coreLib'
project(':coreLib').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../CoreLibs/myJavaCoreLib')
```

**build.gradle** in AndroidApp[1, 2 and 3] *(your A's and B's)*:

```
compile project(':coreLib')
```

Comment: Thank you! This (plus an unrelated bug fix) solved my problem.

Comment: At least! Thank you very much! My head was about to explode!

Comment: Works but subproject outside of the project root is deprecated and scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Is there a solution for this?