# CMake: Android Studio native activity project cannot find thirdparty lib outside the project root

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, build, cmake

For incorporating other opensource libs via CMake, I've checked similar questions such as this one:

[Android Studio: Adding a library outside of the project root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500662/android-studio-adding-a-library-outside-of-the-project-root)

but those are about incorporating Android-Studio lib projects instead of external libs.

In my case, I have a folder structure like this:

- thirdparty

  - category

    - **MyLib**
- src

  - MyAndroidStudioProject

    - build.gradle
    - settings.gradle
    - ...
    - **app**

      - build
      - libs
      - src
      - build.gradle
      - ...

In the project CMakeLists.txt, I then added this

```
target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        native-lib

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib} MyLib)

set (MyLib_DIR ../../../thirdparty/category/MyLib)

# output lib binary
add_subdirectory (${MyLib_DIR} ./MyLib) 

include_directories (${OBOE_DIR}/include)
```

I learned from sample code and assume that the CMake source root is at `src/MyAndroidStudioProject/app`, so `MyLib` is located using relative path accordingly.

However, building the project gives me

```sh
CMake Error at /path/to/src/MyAndroidStudioProject/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt:53 (add_subdirectory):
add_subdirectory given source "../../../thirdparty/category/MyLib"
which is not an existing directory.
```

How should I fix this? Should I configure other settings in the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, solved it myself.

The relative path should be relative to the `CMakeLists.txt` file, located at

```sh
/path/to/src/MyAndroidStudioProject/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt
```

So the correct relative path in my case should be

```
set (MyLib_DIR ../../../../../../thirdparty/category/MyLib)
```

i.e., `CMakeLists.txt` is 3 levels down the `app` folder.