# Creating standalone android library project using Android Studio (0.8.14)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I see there is option to create module/ android library project with in a project, but don't see any way to create a standalone library project/module that could be shared across different projects. It used to be very simple in Eclipse. When I try re-using an existing module within a different project, AndroidStudio simply creates a copy of that module in new project. Thats what I don't want, I want to re-use my existing code. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243269/how-to-share-a-single-library-source-across-multiple-projects) seems to have answer I'm looking for, but not working for latest build for Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways I've tried doing this, a quick and easy way to do this is to symlink your library module directory to a directory in your project and add it to your settings.gradle. A better way to do it is to import the library module as a VCS project (local git works fine) It will still clone the library module into each project but changes made to the library will be consistent across all of the projects using it.