# Spurious module ".." in Android Studio project

Tags: android-studio

I followed the steps in [How to share a single library source across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243269/how-to-share-a-single-library-source-across-multiple-projects) to add an external library to a project.

My project(s) structure:

```
Project MyTest1:
  Module MyLib

Project MyTest2:
  Module MyApp
```

I edited settings.gradle in MyTest2 and added `, ..:MyTest1:MyLib` to the include directive. Now, I am able to see and use the external library project from within `MyTest2` project. Things work as expected.

However, I see a spurious module ".." alongside `MyApp` and `MyLib`. There are no nodes under it and it doesn't seem to cause any problems. I am wondering what exactly is this module for and if there is a way to get rid of it. Regards.

**Edit**

Both my projects are under a directory C:\MyDev. It appears that, anytime you bring up MyTest2 project, AS modifies a file MyTest2.idea\modules.xml and inserts the following line:

```
<module fileurl="file://C:/MyDev.iml" filepath="C:/MyDev.iml" />
```

It then complains that the module was not loaded and creates a fake ".." module. I think this is the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not declare `..:MyTest1:MyLib` as your include. It will cause many problems. Instead, declare it the following way:

```
include ':MyLib'
project(':MyLib').projectDir = new File('../MyTest1/MyLib')
```