# How to include a module in different android projects?

Tags: java, android

In `AndroidStudio`, I want to create a java-class I can use in several projects. I found a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243269/how-to-share-a-single-library-source-across-multiple-projects), in which I followed the alternative method, and created a project named "LibraryProject" with 'app' renamed to "LibraryModule", and I changed `settings.gradle` in the main project to the following content:

```
include ':LibraryModule', ':app'
project(':LibraryModule').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../LibraryProject/LibraryModule')
```

The `LibraryProject` contains a java class named `MyLogger` at the location `LibraryModule/java/com.example.alexander.libraryproject`. But when I try to use it somewhere in the main code (after doing a 'sync'), the `MyLogger` class is not being found.

Maybe the example in the link is outdated? Or I forgot something 'obvious'? Or made an error somewhere else? How to include the `MyLogger` java class from `LibraryProject` into a file in the main project?

Comment: Maybe MyLogger class is package-private? Have you added LibraryModule to app's build.gradle (using: `compile project(':LibraryModule')`)?

Comment: If I do so, I get the following error on a 'sync': `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

Comment: That basically means that path is wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188489/android-studio-gradle-configuration-with-name-default-not-found

Comment: What is the correct path then, given the information in the post? And what path do you mean? Is the answer incorrect I tried to follow?

Comment: I'm talking about LibraryModule's projectDir - Try absolute path there. I'm guessing that settingsDir is defined in settings.gradle?

Comment: I have no idea where 'settingsDir' is defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125172/discussion-between-jereksel-and-alex).