# Android access to classes of library included in another library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I made an android library "messages" that contain classes of messages shared between a client and a server.

I made an App "server" with the library "messages" in dependencies. I can see the classes of "messages"

I made an other android library "client" with the library "messages" in dependencies. I can see classes of "messages"

I made a "Sample" app with library "client" in dependencies. I would like to see classes of "messages" in this app without include the library "messages". I would like to use the classes of "messages" contained in library "client".

Is that possible?

Comment: "I made an other android library "client"": what did you do exactly? Was this library deployed to a Maven repository? Or is this all in the same project? How did you specify the dependencies?

Comment: It's a local library. The final goal is to give the library "Client" to someone who want to communicate with the "server". I would like he doesn't have to include 2 libraries but just the library "client"

Comment: I was asking for the details because this should normally work out of the box.

Comment: You should show the folder structure of your application and the Gradle files. You need to include the library to reference the classes

Answer (score 0):

See [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22747005/6523232)!

However, as you explain, I advise you to make your `messages` library abstract and unknown from `sample`. You should keep reference of this lib only in `client` and `server`. If you really need to use `messages` in `sample`, add dependencies, but that's mean your client/server are not totally autonomous for process (`messages` should be totally transparent).